# Ramification of primes on $\overline{\mathbb Q}$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, prime-factorization, galois-extensions, unramified-extension

My concern arises about the existence of unramified primes in infinite extensions of $\mathbb Q$, particularly in $\overline{\mathbb Q}$.

Now, in general there exist  be a definition of ramification for the ring $\mathbb E$ the all algebraic integers in $\overline{\mathbb Q}$?

In this   [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/153659) is defined the descomposition group of primes in infinite extensions.

Now, suppose that $p$ is a prime number and $\mathfrak p$ is a prime ideal of $\mathbb E$ such that $\mathfrak p\cap \mathbb Z=(p)$ (exist infinitely prime ideals with this feature), and define $k(\mathfrak p)=\mathbb E/\mathfrak p$, which is a algebraic clousure of $\mathbb F_p$.

Let  $G(\mathfrak p)$ and $I(\mathfrak p)$   the descomposition group and the inercia group respectively of $\mathfrak p$, both respect to the absolute Galois group of $\mathbb Q$.

This gives the following sequence

$$0\rightarrow I(\mathfrak p) \stackrel{ }{\rightarrow} G(\mathfrak p) \stackrel{}{\rightarrow} Gal(k(\mathfrak p)/\mathbb F_p) \rightarrow 0$$

1. My first question is about the definining a unramified prime number.

**A prime number $p$ is unramified in $\mathbb E$ if the inercia group $I(\mathfrak p)$ is trivial**

Now we have to see that the definition is not empty.

2. My second question is how to prove that the definition is not empty? i.e there exist prime numbers $p$ such that $I(\mathfrak p)$ is trivial.

Thanks you all.

Comment: There are clearly no unramified primes. The algebraic closure contains $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})$ for all $p$...

Comment: Could you explain your answer more please?

Comment: If a prime ramifies in the small extension then it must in the big extension. In the ring of integers of the above quadratic fields you factorise $(p) =(\sqrt{p})^2$ so $p$ ramifies.

Comment: But precisely, I dont understand why ramification in the small extension implies ramication in the big extension?
Wich are the arguments for this.

Comment: If $\mathbf Q \subset K \subset L$ hen $p\mathcal O_L = (p\mathcal O_K)\mathcal O_L$ (extension of ideals in a tower is transitive), so if $p\mathcal O_K$ has a repeated prime ideal factor then so does $p\mathcal O_L$.

Comment: @KCd this argument applies for L= algebraic clousure of $\mathbb Q$ ?

Comment: No. The concept of ramification can't be described in terms of prime ideal factorization for infinite-degree extensions. Once you check that the property in finite extensions is equivalent to a property in terms of ramification groups then use the description with ramification groups instead as your definition when the extension is infinite.  When $\mathfrak P$ is a prime ideal lying over $p$ in some infinite extension $L/\mathbf Q$, show $I(\mathfrak P|p)$ is the *inverse limit* of the inertia groups $I(\mathfrak P \cap L_i|p)$ with suitable number fields $L_i$ having union $L$.

Comment: OHH right, in this way all primes numbers $p$ are ramified in the ring $\mathbb E$. Thanks

Comment: Don't focus *only* on $\overline{\mathbf Q}$ as an example of an infinite extension.  Consider the $p$-power cyclotomic extension $\mathbf Q(\zeta_{p^\infty}) = \bigcup_{j \geq 1} \mathbf Q(\zeta_{p^j})$.  It has infinite degree over $\mathbf Q$.  Show it is unramified at all primes *other* than $p$ (think first about the number fields $\mathbf Q(\zeta_{p^j})$.

Comment: An appendix to Washington's book on cyclotomic fields describes ramification in infinite-degree algebraic extensions of $\mathbf Q$.